# Unable to authenticate when invoking AWS cmdlets with SSO profile in visual studio code

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-assembly, aws-powershell

I'm using visual studio code with the AWS cli version 2.9.13, I've got an SSO profile configured which I use to authenticate to the AWS service using device code authentication - I can then use this profile to connect to our AWS code commit repository however when trying to invoke any of the AWS PowerShell cmdlets I'm getting the below error returned;

```
 Assembly AWSSDK.SSOOIDC could not be found or loaded. This assembly must be available at runtime to use Amazon.Runtime.Internal.SSOServiceClientHelpers, AWSSDK.Core, Version=3.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=885c28607f98e604.
```

This error is returned each time I use the profile parameter as shown below

```
-ProfileName MySSOProfile
```

What i've done so far;

- Re installed the AWS modules i'm trying to use and installed the
  latest version
- Updated all packages on my WSL to the latest versions
- Installed the AWS Toolkit extension for visual studio, now on version 1.60.0
- Installed AWSSDK.Core --version 3.7.103.13

What do I need to do to resolve this error and so that I can use my authenticated AWS profile to invoke the AWS cmdlets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using SSO credentials from either the .NET SDK or AWS Tools for PowerShell requires a dependency on the SDK's own SSO and SSOOIDC mdoules.

```
Install-Module AWS.Tools.Installer
Install-AWSToolsModule S3, SSO, SSOOIDC

# Since we're not invoking a cmdlet from these modules directly, 
# we must import them explicitly
Import-Module AWS.Tools.SSO
Import-Module AWS.Tools.SSOOIDC

# AWS Tools for PowerShell doesn't support the SSO login flow yet, so login with the CLI
aws sso login --profile MySSOProfile

# Now we can invoke cmdlets using the SSO profile
Get-S3Bucket -ProfileName MySSOProfile
```

See also [Update AWS CLI credentials from AWS IAM Identity Center by using PowerShell](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/update-aws-cli-credentials-from-aws-iam-identity-center-by-using-powershell.html)